# Can I change the configuration of a war package?

Tags: jakarta-ee, war, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have a project that i test, compile and build the war-package for it at my developer-environment. Now I need this package at the test-environment, for which the package needs/has an other configuration. The same later fot the production-environment.

So my question:

do I need to compile and build the project again with the other configuration?

or can I just change the configuration-file inside of the .war file?

Im trying to accomplish this in the context of continuous delivery, which says "build only once", but as I know/read you cant change files in a .war package. 
So Im bit confuse how to solve this without making the build twice.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideal approach is to have the configuration file outside the war as a property file or something.

But for now i would suggest you explode the war are change the configuration file as "build only once" is of higher priority to you.

Comment: the configuration file is a property file. Is it possible to store it outside of the war without further configuration/effort?

Comment: you would have to change the path of the property file. Other than that i wont think there is any change

Comment: thanks. Think im going for that solution, as i like the idea of keeping configuration and build separate.